# What is VB.NET version of PHP's fopen and fwrite, if one exists?

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, fopen, fwrite

I am brand new to .NET and developing as a whole, so please bear with me.  I've been researching a chat application and found a great tutorial using PHP and Ajax.  I've worked around most of it using VB.NET, but can't seem to find out out to set up a type of 'fopen/fwrite'.  Hopefully this makes sense.  Here is the PHP code I'm trying to 'convert':

```
  <?  
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){  
    $text = $_POST['text'];  

    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');  
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");  
    fclose($fp);  
}  
?>
```

If you need any additional info please let me know.  Again, only been programming for 4 months now, after doing sales & marketing for 12 years.  THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) probably comes closest to what you actually want.

But to answer your question: [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) will create a `StreamWriter` on the file, so the verbatim translation would be:

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("log.html")
    writer.Write(...)
End Using
```

Which is pretty much exactly what the method mentioned above does (apologies if I got the syntax slightly wrong, I didn't write VB.NET in about a decade).

Comment: Thanks Joey - both answers look great, a coworker of mine told the importance of the Using statement as well.  I'll upvote both answers once I'm allowed (reputation not high enough yet).

Answer (score 2):

An example of the equivalent vb.net below.

Libraries:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
```

Code:

```
Dim yourFile As System.IO.FileStream
Dim byteData() As Byte
byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Something to add to the file")
yourFile = New FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Append)
yourFile.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
yourFile.Close()
```

Comment: You should really use the `File` methods.